# Company name in Billing and Shipping Columns On Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento2, admin, order-grid

I need to know how to insert **company name** for *Billing and Shipping Columns* on sales order Grid in Magento admin, also *Company name* need to display on both billing/shipping columns under Sales shipment Grid.

Please see the attached image below.[image]